# PHP crypt() function gives different results for different versions

Tags: php

I am upgrading PHP from 5.3.5 to 5.6.3 on the sever.

I am using following code to encrypt the password,

```
public function encrypt($id, $value)
    {
        $salt = substr( '$1$' . md5('+~jkh23hdjfd'.$id.'xyz12345~++-'), 0, 12 );    // !!!Do not change the salt, otherwise all passwords will become invalid!!!
        return crypt($value, $salt);
    }
```

This function gives different results for different php versions. 
In php 5.3.5

```
encrypt( 6534, 'test123' );
o/p: $1$2fb6540d9Ao7XI4cM1akiH4vQlAntu0
```

In php 5.6.3

```
encrypt( 6534, 'test123' );
o/p: $1$2fb6540d$Ao7XI4cM1akiH4vQlAntu0
```

Without proper solution, I cant upgrade the PHP.

What should I do?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: please don't roll your own encryption schemes for passwords use `password_hash` http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Have you tried with PHP 5.5 (which is still supported)?

Comment: And kids, this is why we don't use our own functions for encrypting passwords.

Comment: 5.3.7 did have a bug, but otherwise pretty much every version since PHP 4.3 produces [identical results](http://3v4l.org/EGqZW)

Comment: I know I should not have used own function. I have created this function four years back, at that time I did not think about it.

Comment: @cmorrissey PHP5.3 did not have a password_hash function.

Comment: @Sanky If you read the PHP crypt page it state that it uses its own implementation if one does not exist on the server. Perhaps it is now using a different cipher than before?